# Get list files documents in android Java, NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file, directory

please help me this code, I don't know how android manage files & folders
I use a function that get the list of files documents in android storage, but after check each file, that result illegal, exception throw: No such file or directory

```
 **public void doJob() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Check01952039847501: " + mListFileInput.size());               
                //    list 27 files input
        for (int i = 0; i < mListFileInput.size(); i++) {
            File file = new File(mListFileInput.get(i));
            Log.d(TAG, "Check010684946823046 = " + file);                           
    //    /storage/0F37-7BF9/aliasBook2/Da-Vinci.epub
            Log.d(TAG, "Check010684946823046: check file: " + file.exists());      
            //    false
            try {
                ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    
                // Exception throw "such file or directory android", all files
            }
        }
    }**
```

Note: To get that mListFileInput list, I use recuisive function this:

```
 **public void recuisiveGetEbook(File directory) {
            File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();
            if (fileList != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                    File file = fileList[i];
                     if (!file.getPath().contains("/Android") 
                    && !file.getPath().contains("/data") 
                    && !file.isHidden()) {
                // if that is file
                if (file.isFile() && file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
                    if (file.getName().endsWith(".epub")) {
                        lstResult.add(fileList[i].getPath());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Check019252357: " + fileList[i].getPath());
                    }
                } // if that is folder
                else recuisive1(fileList[i]);
            }
        }
     }
  }**
```

Comment: `recuisiveGetEbook` != `recuisive1` - is this a typo?

Comment: Also better to check if it is a directory before recursing.

Comment: sorry, that is recuisive, I edit when creating the question.I think no problem with recuisive function, it still show result the list of 27 files ebook in my phone.

Comment: the root directory for recuisive is  /storage/0F37-7BF9/ and /storage/emulated/0/ , I using a function from Github to get that root directory

Comment: Add the stacktrace. There are several ways to deal with files in Android. Check here [https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage] Which one are you trying to use? Anyway, you can't simply sniff the whole file system from your app, unless it is rooted.

Comment: and I've just found a very hard to understand that: when debug, the function work great, file.exists return TRUE, create Zipfile success, and then run normal again, it's fail again